# ipython shell awk : Escaping "$" sign

Tags: shell, awk, ipython, zsh

I am figuring out the Ipython shell support. Its seems awk doesn't work  i.e 
following command

```
!ls -l | awk '{print $1}'
```

just prints "1".

How do I pass the "$" sign correctly to shell. I am using zsh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two dollar signs give you a literal dollar sign, so try:

```
!ls -l | awk '{print $$1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping `$` as `\$`

```
!ls -l | awk '{print \$1}'
```

Comment: That was also my first try. But results in error with following message:

awk: {print \1}
awk:        ^ backslash not last character on line